# CollectionView Header ignores left margin on iOS

Tags: maui

I have .net maui application with a header:

```
        <CollectionView.Header>
            <VerticalStackLayout Margin="18,0,18,12">
                <Label Style="{StaticResource TextBodySecondary}"
                       Text="{Binding TotalExpenses, StringFormat={extensions:Translate TotalExpenseTemplate}, Converter={StaticResource AmountFormatConverter}}" />
                <Label Style="{StaticResource TextBodySecondary}"
                       Text="{Binding TotalRevenue, StringFormat={extensions:Translate TotalRevenueTemplate}, Converter={StaticResource AmountFormatConverter}}" />
            </VerticalStackLayout>
        </CollectionView.Header>
```

On Android and Windows the text has a proper margin. On iOS the margin is ignored.

[image]

Funny enough, when I change something hot reload does it actually correct. Is that a known maui issue? And is there a work around?

Comment: (Changed title from "alignment" to "left margin".) I don't see any collectionview ios margin issue at https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues. Please create a new issue there. Make a public github repo with just enough code to run and see the bug. Link to that repo in that new issue. And add a link here to that issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can reproduce the issue that the `Margin` is ignored on iOS. As an alternative workaround, you can wrap your `VerticalStackLayout` in a `ContentView`, then the `Margin` will work as expected.

You can refer to the sample code below:

```
<CollectionView.Header>
      <ContentView>
            <VerticalStackLayout Margin="18,0,18,12">
                <Label Style="{StaticResource TextBodySecondary}"
                       Text="{Binding TotalExpenses, StringFormat={extensions:Translate TotalExpenseTemplate}, Converter={StaticResource AmountFormatConverter}}" />
                <Label Style="{StaticResource TextBodySecondary}"
                       Text="{Binding TotalRevenue, StringFormat={extensions:Translate TotalRevenueTemplate}, Converter={StaticResource AmountFormatConverter}}" />
            </VerticalStackLayout>
     </ContentView>
</CollectionView.Header>
```